# I Have an issue with my windows form application in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, installation

Please Attention

I create a PDF viewer using a third party software in windows forms.when i run my application on windows 7 or 8 it will work fine .but when i run my app on some other pc they have windows 8 then my application give me error of navigation and my file open in window 8 pdf viewer.i am creating a demo for security of pdf file . –

Comment: Certainly we can help.  Consider editing your post to contain _exactly what the problem is_

Comment: Don't downvote give OP time to explain : Said that yes we are here to help you. But you need to provide the question with good details. : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I create  a PDF viewer using a third party software  in windows forms.when i run my application on windows 7 or 8 it will work fine .but when i run my app on some other pc they have windows 8 then my application give me error of navigation and my file open in window 8 pdf viewer.i am creating a demo for security of pdf file .

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @vikas - You can edit your original post. Add details change title and also add codes

Comment: @worksmarter navigation failed error is come on my app and PDF file open in windows default PDF viewer

Comment: @vikas please edit your question. donot comment your question